# Android Virtual Device (AVD) has not 320x320 Android Wear

Tags: android, android-5.0-lollipop, wear-os

After updating SDK to Android OS 5.0.1, now there is no more 320x320 square version of Android Wear ( See attached picture). I found cloning device to change resolution but it is not working ( it needs skin file).

I checked this address for emulator skin properties : **android-studio\plugins\android\lib\device-art-resources**.
Seems they've forgotten to add square 320x320 android device! [image: AVD screenshot]

Comment: Do you have any feedback on my answer below? Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I too noticed that when cloning a square emulator and setting the resolution to 320x320, when launched, the emulator would revert back to 280x280.

To get a 320x320 emulator:

1. Click the pencil next to the AVD to open the AVD Configuration
2. Click "Show Advanced Settings"
3. Set the Skin Definition to "No Skin"

[image: Advanced Settings, skin definition]

Here is the result when choosing "No Skin". The left emulator is the 320x320 and the right emulator is 280x280.

[image: Emulator Comparison]